# compose listview to edit view best practices

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, state, viewmodel

What is the best practice that items list-page to item edit-page with navigation in compose using view model

When click item it goes edit page and i am updating current item in state then i get current item from view model state then assign to remember params but current item title doesnt appear in edit page

**List View**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TodoListView(navController: NavController) { 
    val viewModel = viewModel(TodoListViewModel::class.java)
    val todoListState = viewModel.state

    Scaffold...{ contentPadding ->

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding()),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
        ) {
            val todoItems = todoListState.todoList
            items(todoItems) { todoItem ->
                TodoItemView(navController = navController, item = todoItem, modifyItem = {} )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit View**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun EditItemView(currentItemUuid: Int, navController: NavController) {
    val todoViewModel = viewModel(TodoListViewModel::class.java)
    val state = todoViewModel.state
    todoViewModel.getItem(currentItemUuid)
    val item = state.currentTodo
 
    val dateFormatText = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
    val (title, setTitle) = remember { mutableStateOf(item.title) }
     
 

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            
        }
    ) { contentPaddind ->
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(
                    start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = contentPaddind.calculateTopPadding()
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())

        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = item.title,
                onValueChange = { item.title=it },
                .
                .
                .
```

**ViewModel**

```
class TodoListViewModel(application: Application): BaseViewModel(application) {
 
    var state by mutableStateOf(TodoListState())
        private set

    init {
        getAllItems()
    }

    fun getAllItems() {
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()

            val allItems = dao.getAllItems()
            state = state.copy(todoList = filteredItems)
        }
    }

    fun getItem(id:Int){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            state = state.copy(currentTodo = dao.getItem(id))
        }
    }

    fun editItem(newItem:TodoItem){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            dao.updateItem(newItem)
            getAllItems()
        }
    }

    fun deleteItem(item: TodoItem){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            dao.deleteItem(item)
        }
    }
    fun addItem(item:TodoItem){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            dao.addItem(item)
        }
    }



    data class TodoListState(
            val todoList:List<TodoItem> = emptyList(),
            val currentTodo: TodoItem = defaultItem)

}
```